# connect to sqlite

Tags: objective-c

I'm having some issue connecting to my sqlite database.. I'm using xcode version 4.4.1

here's my code..

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"signature.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        status.text = @"Connected..";

    } else {
        status.text = @"Failed to open/create database..";
    }
}

[filemgr release];
```

Any suggestion..?

Thanks,

Boom

Comment: Also, do you even enter in the first if?

Comment: "Any suggestion..?" - sure, describe your problem precisely.

Comment: Also, currently you're trying to open the database only if it doesn't exist. That makes no sense.

Comment: Hi H2C03 if you read my code i have a condition where i checked my db first before opening it..

Comment: Do you get an error message? If yes, please provide it. If no, did you step throuh your code with a debugger?

Comment: @BoomFloresca "If you read my code" - I have read it. And ***you're trying to open the database only if it doesn't exist, and that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.***

Comment: for your info i have an existing database..

Comment: I was able to fixed using this code..   sqlite3 *newDBconnection;
    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eSignature.db"];

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check if the database exists; `sqlite3_open_v2()` ([reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)) will create the database, if it does not exist, if you pass the flag `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`:

```
NSString *dbPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPath:@"signature.db"];

if (sqlite3_open_v2([dbPath UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE|SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    status.text = @"Connected..";
    // Check the schema and install if it doesn't exist
    sqlite3_close(database);
} else {
    status.text = @"Failed to open/create database..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check if the DB file is in place if you have one in your app's bundle that is pre-built so you can drop it into your documents folder. Of course, as you enhance your app, any schema changes will need to be done in code. Here is some code that I use (that works, but needs to updated a bit)

When opening/creating the DB I use this to specify where the DB file will be. I don't put it with the init because my location is different between iOS and Mac OS X and I want the DB code to work with both:

```
NSString *dbFilePath;
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentFolderPath = searchPaths[0];
dbFilePath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyDBFile.db"];
MyDB* appDB = [[EasySpendLogDB alloc] initWithFile:dbFilePath];
if(!appDB) {
    // show error
    return;
}
```

This is in my DB access class. It uses some wrapper classes I wrote:

```
- (id) initWithFile: (NSString*) filePathName {
if(!(self = [super init])) return nil;

BOOL myPathIsDir;
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                         fileExistsAtPath: filePathName
                         isDirectory: &myPathIsDir];
NSString *backupDbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                  pathForResource:@"MyDBFile"
                                  ofType:@"db"];

if (backupDbPath != nil && !fileExists) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                            copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath
                            toPath:filePathName
                            error:nil];
}

db = [[ABSQLiteDB alloc] init];
if(![db connect:filePathName]) {
    return nil;
}

[self checkSchema]; // this is where schema updates are done (see project sample)

return self;
}
```

You may also want to check out this objective-c wrapper I wrote that has a sample project: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite